# Mobile problems with slick slideshow

Tags: mobile, slider, slideshow, slick.js

I'm using slick-slider from ken wheeler. The slider works pretty well on mobile up to 480px screen width. Below it results in a horrible heigth and width problem, as you can see in the video (can not show you the site because of ssh keys / staging).

**Video**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1w4yz9fv4mlyv24/slick-slideshow-problem.mov?dl=0

Do you have a clue what is going on here and why there is such a height problem / I can not see the slides?

They seem to be moved out of the screens, but I have no clue why tbh...

I hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance
Sascha